# Proving "if A or B, then C"

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Suppose that I know that the following statements hold

1. If A, then C;
2. If B, then C.

But "if A, then C" AND "if B, then C" is logically equivalent to

3. If A or B, then C

So I have two equivalent options when writting a proposition: state items 1 and 2 or state item 3.

Both options are proved in the same way: "Suppose A holds, then we have C... Suppose B holds, then we have C."

Are these ideas correct?

Comment: That seems about right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See the truth table for the following tautology:

[image]

Source: https://www.erpelstolz.at/gateway/TruthTable.html